# psql in Windows Command Prompt: How to type in new line?

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd, psql

psql in Windows Command Prompt: How to type in new line?

I need type in many lines

[image]

but I don't know how to do?

[image]

Comment: Just include the open parenthesis `(` on the first line, so that `psql` knows that more input is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL in Linux or Windows environment you have to use the following commands for your db purpsoses,

use `\l` for view\list the databases that are available.

use `\c` to select the databases as below,

```
postgres=# \c testdb
```

if there any db named ***testddb***

use `\d` for view the `relations` or `tables` in that database

use `d+` to describe a table

```
postgres=# \d+ users
```

In your case use the table creation script as below

```
postgres=# \c warehouse_db 

warehouse_db=# CREATE TABLE warehouse_tbl (
warehouse_db(# warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
warehouse_db(# warehouse_name TEXT NOT NULL,
warehouse_db(# year_created INTEGER,
warehouse_db(# street_address TEXT,
warehouse_db(# city CHARACTER VARYING(100),
warehouse_db(# state CHARACTER VARYING(2),
warehouse_db(# zip CHARACTER VARYING(10)
warehouse_db(# );
```

So the output is

`CREATE TABLE`

Then describe your table as below ,

```
warehouse_db=# \d+ warehouse_tbl
```

To quit form the `postgres` terminal type as below,

```
warehouse_db=# \q
```

Here I have tested your syntax with PostgreSQL version 11.9 . Above SQL script for table creation works well with that version.

I've got error when using ,

`constant "PRIM_KEY" PRIMARY KEY (warehouse_id)`

So I have modified your code according to PostgreSQL version 11.9   manual.

#### Update

According to [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt)'s comment corrected the SQL script is ,

```
warehouse_db=# CREATE TABLE warehouse_tbl (
warehouse_db(# warehouse_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
warehouse_db(# warehouse_name TEXT NOT NULL,
warehouse_db(# year_created INTEGER,
warehouse_db(# street_address TEXT,
warehouse_db(# city CHARACTER VARYING(100),
warehouse_db(# state CHARACTER VARYING(2),
warehouse_db(# zip CHARACTER VARYING(10),
warehouse_db(# CONSTRAINT "PRIM_KEY" PRIMARY KEY(warehouse_id)
warehouse_db(# );
```

This will work on your windows machine.

Comment: You've got an error because you replaced `CONSTRAINT` with `constant`.

Answer (score 1):

In `pgsql` command line, use

```
\e
```

Then edit in text editor many lines of SQL Script

[image]